# How would you read and count a huge list with code

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command-line

I have a list of 20 million or so names (average 6 chars), one each line, saved in either a .csv or a txt file.

Some names appear more than twice, other's appear only once. I only want those who appear more than x amount of times to do resaved into another list of the names with the total number amount of times it appeared in the file next to each name, those who appeared less than x being deleted.

(I know this won't be interesting, but is what I've been trying to do):
-Tried using .bat and powershell because it's all I KIND OF know
Basically my code checked each line and tried to save it to a either a `%variable%` or `$variable`, respectively 
-if the variable exists, s`et %(name)(number)%+1` and save to the variable `%name%%namenumber%`
nextline (or check all content with get-content) 
-When it finishes each %name% is printed with `%namenumber`) next to it to show the amount

I realised this was retarded and tried using arrays but I couldn't get it to work.

I don't code but I thought the puzzle was fun. It was for the first hour or so, but I have work to do which relates to this and I don't know enough about the language to do it

Comment: This is better done in PowerShell than batch; I commend to your attention the cmdlets [`Get-Content`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6), [`Import-CSV`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6), [`Sort-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-6) and [`Where-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6)

Comment: You should also read and understand how the [PowerShell pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-6) works; it is _not_ the way the Batch or *ix shell pipeline works. Finally, you will find that the [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help?view=powershell-6) and [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command?view=powershell-6) cmdlets will also be extremely helpful.

Comment: I would add [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-6) to the mix.

Comment: Group-Object would normally be right and might still work but with 20 million or so records I would expect it to take approximately 47 years...

Comment: @EBGreen `-NoElement` should make a difference in this scenario

Comment: Great...now you've all made me go write code to benchmark this scenario. I hope you're all proud of what you've done...

Comment: Any idea how many unique names there are?

Comment: With 20 million records, I would use a language that compiles to a native executable.

Comment: @EBGreen - this should be about 120MB of data. I don't expect powershell taking 47 years to work its way through that ;). Did you benchmark it?

Comment: I created a file that is 123MB which is a little over 16,000,000 random 6 character strings. Not a perfect set up but good enough for what I expect to have happen. Get-Content | Group-Object has been running for 36 minutes now and the PS session is up to about 500MB of memory usage. I predict that it won't be done by this time tommorrow if it doesn't get an out of memory error first. Powershell just doesn't scale well for large data sets. At the very least I would highly recommend leveraging .Net classes to do something like this rather than powershell. A fully compiled language would be good.

Comment: Woops...forgot the -NoElement. I have started it over.

Comment: @EBGreen - still running?

Comment: Yep. been running for about 91 hours now. It is up to 2.8GB memory consumption.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers still running. Up to 3.2GB.

Comment: @EBGreen - well. That's... slow. I think you've made your case ;)

Comment: Yeah, now I'm just curious to see how ling it takes and how much memory it consumes. I have 32GB on this box so I'll just let it run. :)

Comment: Ok, well it is coming up on a week that it has been running and I need to reboot this box. It got up to just under 4GB memory consumption.